# CSS: Can I use the classes of nested elements to narrow css down?

Tags: css

Here is an example of what I have:

```
<div class="node node-blog">
  <div class="field-item even">
    <img src="image.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is apply a style to the img element only when inside the node-blog and field-item divs, but this does not work:

```
.node-blog .field-item img {float:right;}
```

Sure I am doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try:
.node-blog .field-item img {float:right!important;}
...another rule may be more selective

Comment: Don't do this please. It spreads like a virus, and soon you will have all your styles set as !important. It is far better to learn about css specificity and create your style sheets such that they work without !important.

Comment: I voted this answer up because it's a really quick way to see if specificity is the root of the problem.  `!important` is good for diagnosing the problem, and since there was nothing wrong with the code provided in the question, diagnosis (this answer) was the best place to start.  But as @david said, you really aren't going to want to use `!important` to "solve" the problem unless you're excited about future headaches.

Answer (score 2):

### Provided style's fine

Unless you have other errors in your CSS file, this line seems correct. It's most probably something very stupid. Maybe some typo in your actual code if you haven't actually copy-pasted it here...

As long as your `img` is contained within a subtree of `.field-item` that is in a subtree of `.node-blog` this should work. You don't have to provide the whole path.

### Other rule overrides yours

Unless you have a different rule on `img` that sets float to it. CSS style of it

- Must be more specific to the one provided to override yours.
- Is less specific but sets float setting as `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

All else being equal, it should work. The problem is in a piece of code you aren't sharing with us.

Comment: There are actually a couple of other div's in between the field-item and node-blog div, do I have to list each one?

Comment: No. You're using descendent selectors, not child selectors.

Comment: Just tested it, and yes I had to add all of them in, it is working now.

Comment: @Shane Grant: in that case your cascade had lower priority. The `!important` trick should just as well work. Have you checked which style definition overrode yours? If it works with the complete path then something else has been overriding it that was more exact over your definition.

Comment: `!important` is something of a sledgehammer, and you can't double !important something. It is almost always better to write selectors that are specific enough to override anything you want to override.

Comment: "better to write selectors that are specific..." absolutely, but `!important` can be a good way to figure out if the problem is related to cascading or a typo that you overlooked.

Comment: @David Dornward, @mlms13: Sometimes you have to override an `!important` with a more specific style that also sets it as `!important`. I know I would b$#@h about the CSS author but sometimes 'tis that way.